# How to use module.exports to export async function

Tags: javascript, express, async-await

I am unable to return the result of an async function to the route I am calling.  How can I successfully do this?

I am trying to export a token from file token_generator.js and display it on route ('/') using Express. I import the function from other file.

```
const tokenGenerator = require('./src/token_generator');
```

I have a simple route to call that function output.

```
app.get('/', async function (request, response) {
  const identity = request.query.identity || 'identity';
  const room = request.query.room;
  response.send(tokenGenerator(identity, room));
});
```

In my token_generator, I use async/await to retrieve and generate token.  I log it prior to export and it appears in my console, but never gets to the webpage.

```
async function tokenGenerator(identity, room) {

  const token = new AccessToken(
    process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
    process.env.TWILIO_API_KEY,
    process.env.TWILIO_API_SECRET
  );

  let grant = new VideoGrant();
  token.identity = Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^a-z]+/g, '').substr(0, 8);
  grant.room = await getRoomId(room);
  token.addGrant(grant);
  console.log(token.toJwt());
  return await token.toJwt();
}

module.exports = tokenGenerator;
```

How can I get the token to show up on the webpage?  I had a working version of this prior, with very similar code - but want to use async/await as its better practice than my previous code.  I suppose there must be a different way to call the function in Express?  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.get('/', async function (request, response) {
  const identity = request.query.identity || 'identity';
  const room = request.query.room;
  // Since your tokenGenerator is async, you need await to get its result
  response.send(await tokenGenerator(identity, room));
});
```

Comment: haha -- works, easy enough.  thanks Hao.  I will update answer in 5 mins when it allows me to.